# How TO join many tables into one in Access

Tags: ms-access

I had a table with some 25000 records and 75 fields. For easier analysis i broke them down into 10 tables with 2500 records each. now i want to put them back together to form a single table. how do i write a query.
i tried a select query like select * from (table1, table2.....)
but i get error as query is too complex.

tksy

Comment: Could you post the table structure & the query, which throws error of "too many fields defined"?

Comment: THE TABLE HAS 72 COLUMNS ALL ARE IDENTICAL IN ALL TABLES WITH SIMILAR DATA TYPES.
QUERY WAS
select * from table1
union
select * from table2

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly select the field, to ensure a perfect match when you use UNION.

For example,

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    Surname
FROM
    tblCustomer1

UNION

SELECT
    Name [Firstname],
    Surname
FROM
    tblCustomer2
```

Select the specific columns you want and make sure they are all named identically and contain the same data type.

Comment: I NEED ALL THE COLUMNS SOME 72 COLUMNS IN AL TABLES

Comment: You'll need to list them all then - the good news is that you can copy and paste it once you've listed it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableA
union
...
select * from tableN
```

Comment: is there counter ? Auto Identity field of somekind ?

Comment: could be it, try to exclude it from selection

Comment: maybe you missed some column here and there ? try to compact the database could be internal counter causing this because Access has 255 columns per table limitation and even if you delete columns settings for counter are saved